# Why is heatmap turning red in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, heat-map

I'm using QGIS 3.16.1.  I'm creating a heatmap using the symbology.  At first it appears like a normal heatmap, but it is still rendering.  When it finishes the whole heatmap turns red.  Here's a before and after screenshot.

What is happening here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: radius is too big. Check the units, by default it is in millimeters so it is scale dependent

Comment: You have asked several questions about heatmaps and got several answers and comments. You should read these and try to apply what is recommended there. Once again: radius and pixel size are important, try to get an understanding what their effect is. For radius, play around with the values in the points layer heatmap rendering style to get an idea of the effect of changing radius before running the Hetamap tool.